# Flutter / Android Studio: can you do a build for iOS in a Windows PC?

Tags: ios, android-studio, flutter

I've built a small simple app with Flutter / Android Studio, on a Windows 10 PC.  I'm successfully building APKs and installing them on my Android smartphone, and it's fine.

I want to see if I can build for an iphone, but when I selected Build - Flutter - Build iOS, it started OK but then I got the message: "Building for iOS is only supported on the Mac."

Does this mean I can't build an iOS version using a PC?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sure, you can ONLY build to iPhone from a Mac - sorry for the bad news!

Comment: check codemagic

Comment: That's how Apple make their money. Have to buy a Mac (people will tell you about using Code magic, Hackintish, virtual machines running Mac OS, etc.... good luck with all of that), have to pay them USD99 a year to  put apps on the App Store, etc. This is not a Flutter / Google issue, it's Apple's business model.